# Optimize response time for slim REST API

Tags: angular, server, localhost, rest, slim-3

I am using Slim to create the server side of my API, this API is consumed by Angular (this API is run on local).
Everything is working but the problem I'm having is that it takes a long time for the server to send a response. With Postman, it shows that a simple GET request takes 800~1000ms to get the response.
I am wondering if there is a way to reduce this time, either by changing Slim configuration (.htaccess? routes? code?...) or localhost configuration (httpd.conf, mySQL config...)?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution for this. After trying different configurations, I decided to uninstalled my WAMP server and reinstalled it. By doing this the response time went from 800~1000 ms to 80~100 ms.